# Sending email from various domains

Tags: email, smtp

We are building hosted software service that is used by multiple customers.

These customers want to communicate with their customers (end customer). So, today we send it from our domain: example.com

However, we would like to send email to come from their specific domains. When we put their customer emails in Reply-To - it shows up as "on behalf" in clients like outlook.

What are the ways to send email from their domain without installing software on their network?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just change the "From" field in whatever email client you are using for sending the emails. You will need to ensure that the SMTP server you are sending from does not enforce any kind of 'from' restrictions.

Most commercial ISP mail servers will not permit this for sending, so you may need to either host your own, or find a commercial one that supports this.

Comment: We do host our own and the problem is with this method it shows up as "on behalf" in Outlook client. We need to find a way to eliminate this

Comment: @IMHO, as I mentioned, to get around this, don't change the "reply-to", change the "from" address.